# Errors using Bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, bulkinsert

I have a dataset which I want to import into an sql table.
A small sample of the data looks like:

```
Ticker,BloombergID,Sedol,RICCode,Cusip,UnderDescription,Description,CountryOfIssuer,CountryOfIssue,Industry,Sector,MarketValue,NotionalExposure,ImpliedVolatility,Delta,DeltaAdjExp,Gamma,Rho,Theta,Vega,ExchangeContractCode,ExpiryDate,CallPut,StrikePrice,Price,SaxoSymbolCode,FixedSaxoSymbolCode,ExpiryDateFixed
1JY78U5,,,1JY78U5,99A0TT759,JAPANESE YEN SEP15 FUTURE CME,JAPANESE YEN SEP15 PUT @ 0.78 EXP 09/04/2015,United States,United States,Specialized Finance,Financials,3975,625574.99,0.1,-0.16,,4.17,0,0,0,j1,9/4/2015,0,0.78,0.01,6J/U15P0.01:xcme                       ,6J/U15P0.78:xcme,20150904
1JY755U5,,,1JY755U5,99A16JKW0,JAPANESE YEN SEP15 FUTURE CME,JAPANESE YEN SEP15 PUT @ 0.755 EXP 09/04/2015,United States,United States,Specialized Finance,Financials,1012.5,312787.49,0.11,-0.09,,2.53,0,0,0,j1,9/4/2015,0,0.755,0,6J/U15P0.01:xcme                       ,6J/U15P0.755:xcme,20150904
1JY765U5,,,1JY765U5,99A0YZT71,JAPANESE YEN SEP15 FUTURE CME,JAPANESE YEN SEP15 PUT @ 0.765 EXP 09/04/2015,United States,United States,Specialized Finance,Financials,-450,-104262.5,0.11,-0.12,,3.13,0,0,0,j1,9/4/2015,0,0.765,0,6J/U15P0.01:xcme                       ,6J/U15P0.765:xcme,20150904
```

Where the last column is calculated as

```
=VALUE(YEAR(ExpiryDate)&IF(MONTH(ExpiryDate)<10,0&MONTH(ExpiryDate),MONTH(ExpiryDate))&IF(DAY(ExpiryDate)<10,0&DAY(ExpiryDate),DAY(ExpiryDate)))`
```

Using Excel, which I then save as a CSV(comma seperated) file. (as opposed to semicolon seperated)

I create a SQL table using

```
USE [RiskMart]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [meta].[ETOGreeks20150320]    Script Date: 3/23/2015 4:47:07 PM ******/
DROP TABLE [meta].[ETOGreeks20150320]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [meta].[ETOGreeks20150320](
    [Ticker] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [BloombergID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Sedol] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [RICCode] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Cusip] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [UnderDescription] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CountryOfIssuer] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CountryOfIssue] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Industry] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Sector] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [MarketValue] [float] NULL,
    [NotionalExposure] [float] NULL,
    [ImpliedVolatility] [float] NULL,
    [Delta] [float] NULL,
    [DeltaAdjExp] [float] NULL,
    [Gamma] [float] NULL,
    [Rho] [float] NULL,
    [Theta] [float] NULL,
    [Vega] [float] NULL,
    [ExchangeContractCode] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ExpiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CallPut] [bit] NULL,
    [StrikePrice] [float] NULL,
    [Price] [float] NULL,
    [SaxoSymbolCode] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [FixedSaxoSymbolCode] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ExpiryDateFixed] [int] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

When I use the bulk insert

```
BULK
INSERT RiskMart.meta.ETOGreeks20150320
FROM '\\path\ETO Greeks.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

I get following error:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for
>   row 1, column 28 (ExpiryDateFixed).

I have tried to change the data type of the last column to varchar(255), but that only gives me a new error message:

> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (truncation) for row 1, column 28 (ExpiryDateFixed).

I really have no idea what to do.
Could you please help me?

P.s. The reason I create the column "ExpiryDateFixed" is because the "ExpiryDate" column is an excel date time value, but when I try to import it into SQL as a "smalldatetime"-column it returns 1900-1-1 as the date.

Additional info:
I use a PC with windows 7, Excel proffesional 2010, SQL server 2012 and SQL Server 2014,
I have created the table in 2014 and use 2012 to do bulk insert. I have used this setup for half a year, and have not experienced any problems.

Comment: Please make sure that none of the other columns have commas in them.

Comment: @Bejnamin if I use the excel "Find and Select" to search for them in the CSV file it finds no commas.

Comment: One of the columns has unexpected data and SQL Server gets out of sync and keeps looking for data that matches the number of columns. When it reaches the last column (it sees the \n in the file) it realizes its lost and blames the last column when something was amiss in one of the previous columns. By the way when I do select cast('20150904' as datetime) it converts the column to datetime just fine. YYYYMMDD is the preferred way of declared a date - SQL Server can alway translate it.